Why is my dart data class generator extension not working?
I have installed Dart data class generator for flutter. It was working fine when I first installed it - While I click on a class and and click on right click button, I used to get various options of data classes to be generated such as copywith, equatable, constructor etc. I no longer see that option when I right click now. Not sure what has changed. Anyone has experienced the same?

Which IDE are you using?

The IDE thats used is VSCode

Please make sure that associated generated file is present in the folder. Try restarting VSCode, check if Flutter & Dart extension is installed.
